# Multi-class Classification using multiple binary models versus single model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, classification

Let's assume that my dataset contains pictures of cats, wolves, bears, and other random pics. I would like to build an application to classify a new picture into the existing categories (three animals + irrelevant).

In doing so, I can build a multi-output CNN model. And my question is that: if I were to build 3 binary-output CNN models separately (for cats, wolves, and bears respectively), what would happen to the accuracy of prediction?

Would the 3 binary-output models make more accurate predictions for that they are specialized? Or would the multi-output model make more accurate predictions as it can exploit more intricacy out of the data? And is there a general theory that can show us (mathematically) what is supposed to happen?

Comment: There are similar discussions about this on Cross Validated: [[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182216/multiclass-vs-one-vs-all-vs-one-vs-one-classification), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52104/multinomial-logistic-regression-vs-one-vs-rest-binary-logistic-regression), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313549/why-decision-boundary-differs-between-multinomial-softmax-and-one-vs-rest-logi)]; some don't have answers. I imagine the accuracies (assuming you use argmax on the ensemble) would be similar in general.

Comment: Since this question isn't directly related to implementation or programming, perhaps it would be better to close and ask over there.